# Native/default colors for hovered title text and background

Tags: html, css, hover

Natively in chrome/firefox, hovering over an element shows its title with a yellow background with black text.

Does anyone know the ***exact*** HEX or RGB colors for each?

thanks,
tim

Comment: It's OS specific, are you using Linux or Windows, Mac?

Comment: About to say that, in Windows is not yellow but rather a white to gray degration with black color.

Comment: Yeah, its a nice color. I've wondered at times what color it was. But its not like we can check the source code. (at least I dont know where to check)

Comment: Mac, thanks @LEOPiC for the clarification on Windows. If someone knew what either defaults were that'd be great...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Took a screen capture, opened it in photoshop, used the color picker to find the values.

In OSX/Chrome the tooltip yellow background is:

```
#ffffca
```

In OSX/Chrome the tooltip text is:

```
#000023
```

In OSX/FF the tooltip yellow background is:

```
#feffcd
```

in OSX/FF the tooltip text is:

```
#000
```

There are actually minor variations at some points in the Chrome bg, it's not a purely solid color. I'm not sure what would cause that anomaly. But the hex value I took was the most consistent, and any variations are negligible anyway.

Text is of course antialiased, and values were taken from what I perceived to be the darkest area of the text, which would correspond to its actual RGB/HEX value.

Comment: Most excellent browser plugin is [**ColorZilla**](http://www.colorzilla.com/) for both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @arttronics Thanks, I installed it and I'm sure it will prove a time saver! Doesn't really work in this particular case though, because the tooltip disappears as soon as you move the mouse/picker over it.

Comment: When it disappears, the color is saved to the clipboard. Right click on the webpage and choose ColorZilla (Webpage DOM Color Analyzer) and see every CSS style with it's color information.

Comment: I don't have the contextual right-click option you describe in OSX/Chrome. The ColorZilla menu does have a 'webpage color analyzer' options, but I don't think it works the way you describe. It shows all the CSS colors on the page, but not tooltip colors, since tooltips are defined by the browser itself, not the webpage?

Comment: Ah, I missed the part about **browsers native tooltip color scheme**. Now I understand what you said. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Hexidecimal color value for Windows tooltip background:

```
FFFFE1
```

Hexidecimal color value for Linux:

```
F6F6B9
```

RGB color value for Windows tooltip background:

```
(255,255,225)
```

RGB color value for Linux tooltip background:

```
(246,246,185)
```

Comment: This is the very first time that I have seen 2 diff HEX colors share the same RGB color (#ffffff and #ffffe1) and they are both right! http://www.colorhexa.com/ffffe1 http://www.colorhexa.com/ffffff

Answer (score 0):

From RGB space, you convert to Hunter-Lab space, use L condition(>0.5) to set the appropriate value,
[http://dataanalysers.com/00ff00](http://web.archive.org/web/20140202062244/http://dataanalysers.com/00ff00)