# attriibute title box change width and height css only

Tags: html, css

```
<li><a class="fancypdf" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Proin eget mattis enim. Nam at laoreet sapien. Nulla facilisi. Aenean commodo egestas 
odio id bibendum. Vestibulum commodo, justo et dignissim congue, dolor sem finibus nisi, 
ac tempus risus lacus nec justo. Fusce tincidunt ante nec malesuada imperdiet." 
href="pdf/pdffile.pdf">`if hover title will appear`</a><br></li>
```

This is a list with attribute title with it when you hover it a box with appear with the content of title but if the title is long like my example the box with be very width what i want is the box to be just enough wide and extend in height.
Is there a way to do this without using like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tDQWN/). This fiddle is all i can see to do this kind of css style

`UPDATE`

this is the css i used

```
a[title]:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  width:600px;
}
```

Comment: The referenced fiddle actually IS your answer unless I am not getting what you are aiming at, since the default tooltip is a browser feature.

Comment: i am looking for another way is there another way i just want it like the old one just different width and height i tried the fiddle  and change the width and height it didnt work..i want it as simple as possible no other details just change the width and height

Comment: agreed with @Paul... what "didnt work"? it's easy like hell, just add a width and height and probably remove `white-space: nowrap;`...

Comment: Solution may be easy but we are not understanding the question.

Comment: As I said the tooltips are browser dependent, so to achieve the same look and feel, you would need to write CSS for each browser. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060617/native-default-colors-for-hovered-title-text-and-background

Comment: it didnt work meaning the box didnt change width and height and a new content keeps appearing beside the anchor which is the same exact content that is in the box..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, you want to disable the default title tooltip for elements and make your own, which should look very similar to the default one. The problem with your example fiddle is, that along with the custom CSS tooltip, the browser also shows the default tooltip (with a delay).

To change that, you could turn title attributes to data-title attributes and change the CSS accordingly:

```
a[title]:hover:after { content: attr(title); ... }
```

must be changed to

```
a[data-title]:hover:after { content: attr(data-title); ... }
```

See the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tDQWN/5450/). The first link has only the custom CSS tooltip, the second link shows the default browser tooltip.

Comment: i see what is the difference with data-title and title i am hoping there wont be any drawback for it this is what i mean so i can now change the width and height of the box..

Comment: One drawback is that screen readers won't read out the title attribute (as there is none). Other than that I can't think of anything else right now. "data-?" attributes are valid, see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Comment: why is it locked below the ul i want it right next to the li can you give me advice to fix it

Comment: I am not a clairvoyant. ;) In the fiddle, there is no ul/li and your example only has a li element. But you should play around with the position/left/top attributes in CSS to move the tooltip around.